# Как можно сделать экспорт vue в excel

Tags: json, vue.js, excel

Нужно экспортировать данные из модалки в ексель.

Это модалка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использовав vue-json-excel смогла сделать экспорт данных таблицы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но там только сама таблица как можно оформить header и footer так чтобы была как на модалке? и плюс как задать таблице border и font. Спасибо за любой совет. Или чтобы заголовки и футер принимали значения массива

Код:

```
<template #modal-footer>
                <download-excel 
                    :data="statement_data" 
                    class="btn btn-primary" 
                    :fields="json_fields" 
                    type="xls" 
                    name="filename" 
                    :before-generate="startDownload" 
                    :before-finish="finishDownload"
                    :header="json_fields_2"
                    :footer="exportFooter"
                >
                    Сохранить в Excel
                </download-excel>
            </template>
```

Значения json_fields:

```
json_fields: {
            '№': 'index',
            'Ф.И.О.': 'person',    
            'Время': 'time',
            'Баллы': 'points',
            'Оценка': 'rating_est',
            'Примечание': 'description',            
        },
```

И в :header="json_fields_2" и :footer="exportFooter" я пробовала дать список словарей не принимает. А данные заголовка меняются должны

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то боюсь что этого сделать не получится с в данных условиях, ибо вы экспортируете данные из таблицы, но не саму таблицу. Все опции кастомизации `vue-json-excel` можно посмотреть [здесь](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-json-excel#props-list).

Поэтому вам нужно найти либу, которая имеет достаточно опций для кастомизации типа `js-xlsx`, `xlsx-style` и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую